# Google API Cloud identity groups().create(): what is the field customer_id?

Tags: python, api, google-groups, google-cloud-identity

I would like to create a group using the API Cloud Identity and the command groups().create().

To do so, I'v used the example provided by Google:

```
def create_google_group(service, customer_id, group_id, group_display_name, group_description):
    group_key = {"id": group_id}
    group = {
        "parent": "customers/" + customer_id,
        "description": group_description,
        "displayName": group_display_name,
        "groupKey": group_key,
        # Set the label to specify creation of a Google Group.
        "labels": {
          "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum": ""
        }
    }

    try:
        request = service.groups().create(body=group)
        request.uri += "&initialGroupConfig=WITH_INITIAL_OWNER"
        response = request.execute()
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

But I got an issue:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1/groups?alt=json&initialGroupConfig=WITH_INITIAL_OWNER returned "Invalid resource.parent". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'resource.parent', 'description': 'Invalid resource.parent'}]}]">
```

For the field **customer_id**, I tried without any success:

- data from https://console.developers.google.com/

  - ID clients OAuth 2.0, ID_client: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  - idem but only: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  - project identifier: 'yyyy-yyyy-123456'
- 'me'
- 'my_email@example.com'
- 'my_customer'

Thank you in advance for your support to understand what is expected for the field **customer_id**!

Answer (score 2):

You can find your customer ID through the Admin console.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/10070793?hl=en

There are several other ways to find it as well.

- User Resource from AdminSDK (customerId field - [docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users))
- Organization API for GCP customers (directoryCustomerId field - [docs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/organizations#OrganizationOwner))

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've no admin rights! However, even when I want to get the list of the groups I need the customerId.

Comment: You can get the customer ID without admin rights. Try the organizations.list API.

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations/list

Comment: I tried but I got only empty answers {}  with code 200 (OK)